# PyGtk thread not running until main quits

Tags: python, gtk

I've been trying to sort this problem for hours now, scouring the web and reading the documentation hasn't helped. I'm trying to perform a long running task in a separate thread and display the progress in a progress bar in the UI. The new thread is started but is not given any time until the main loop quits, I have called `Gdk.threads_init()` before `Gtk.main` and I have surrounded UI calls with `Gdk.threads_enter()` and `Gdk.threads_leave()`.

The following code reproduces the problem, clicking on the 'start' button has no effect, but once the window is closed and the main loop quits I see the second thread doing work (i.e I see the print statements half a second apart)

```
class App(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.connect("destroy", self.on_destroy)

        self.layout = Gtk.VBox()
        self.progress = Gtk.ProgressBar()
        self.layout.pack_start(self.progress, False, False, 0)

        self.set_size_request(100,100)

        self.go_button = Gtk.Button("Start")
        self.go_button.connect("clicked", self.do_work_subclass)
        self.layout.pack_start(self.go_button, False, False, 0)

        self.add(self.layout)
        self.show_all()



    def on_destroy(widget, event):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def do_work(self, widget):
        def worker_thread():
            so_far = 0
            while so_far < 10:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print("work so far: %s" % so_far)
                Gdk.threads_enter()
                try:
                    if so_far > 0:
                        self.progress.set_fraction(so_far / 10.0)
                finally:
                    Gdk.threads_leave()
                so_far += 1
        threading.Thread(target=worker_thread).start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    Gdk.threads_init()
    Gdk.threads_enter()
    Gtk.main()
    Gdk.threads_leave()
```

Could this be related to the fact that I am using Gtk3?

Comment: Do you think this code will run with GTK 2.x? I am eager to test this when you get a solution...

Comment: Okay, should have tested that before, yes it works with gtk 2.28. But I would much rather use Gtk3 so any suggestiosn welcome.

Comment: After spending many frustrated hours on this I find the answer almost as soon as I post the question, oh well. The problem is that you need to call `GLib.thread_init()` rather than `Gdk.threads_init()`. I don't have the rep to answer my own question for another 7 hours, will do so when I can.

Comment: Please include your imports on the working code, so other users will more easily copy/paste it to a script. Thanks for caring!

Answer (score 4):

And having spent hours trying to find an answer before posting a question I find the solution minutes after posting. Turns out (from [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=121303)) that for GTK3 you need to call `GLib.threads_init()`, the code works with an initial `from gi.repository import GLib` and a `GLib.threads_init()` before the call to `Gtk.main()`, so a working version of the code looks like this:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk,Gdk, GLib
import threading 
import time

class App(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.connect("destroy", self.on_destroy)

        self.layout = Gtk.VBox()
        self.progress = Gtk.ProgressBar()
        self.layout.pack_start(self.progress, False, False, 0)

        self.set_size_request(100,100)

        self.go_button = Gtk.Button("Start")
        self.go_button.connect("clicked", self.do_work)
        self.layout.pack_start(self.go_button, False, False, 0)

        self.add(self.layout)
        self.show_all()



    def on_destroy(widget, event):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def do_work(self, widget):
        def worker_thread():
            so_far = 0
            while so_far < 10:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print("work so far: %s" % so_far)
                Gdk.threads_enter()
                try:
                    if so_far > 0:
                        self.progress.set_fraction(so_far / 10.0)
                finally:
                    Gdk.threads_leave()
                so_far += 1
        threading.Thread(target=worker_thread).start()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    GLib.threads_init()
    Gdk.threads_init()
    Gdk.threads_enter()
    Gtk.main()
    Gdk.threads_leave()
```

Comment: This ended up being my problem also. While I was making the call to threads_init() the key is to do it *before* invoking main().